# HQL query jasper report

Tags: hibernate

I have made query using Criteria in hibernate ,it is working fine.

Code:

```
 List<HmsInventoryStockDetail> stockList = null;
                Criteria crt = session.createCriteria(HmsInventoryStockDetail.class);
                crt.createAlias("itemMaster", "item");
                if (!itemName.equals("")) {
                    crt.add(Restrictions.eq("item.itemName", itemName));

                }
                if (!itemType.equals("")) {
                    crt.add(Restrictions.eq("item.itemTypeMaster.itemType", itemType));
                }
                if (!manufacturerName.equals("")) {
                    crt.add(Restrictions.eq("item.manufacturerMaster.manufacturerName", manufacturerName));
                }
                if (!batchNumber.equals("")) {
                    crt.add(Restrictions.eq("batchNumber", batchNumber));
                }
                if (!rackNo.equals("")) {

                    crt.add(Restrictions.eq("item.rackMaster.rackNo", rackNo));
                }
                if (expiryDate != null) {
                    crt.add(Restrictions.le("expiryDate", expiryDate));
                }
                stockList = crt.list();
```

but i need parallel Hql query for this statemen.
Thanks

Comment: A criteria query doesn't generate HQL. It generates SQL directly.

Comment: Why would you go for HQL instead of Criteria? Usually people go the other way.